# Other thread wont let me change Activity layout!? Android

Tags: android, multithreading, android-activity, progressdialog, alter

**SOLUTION:**

It might not be the best or the prettiest solution, but it works. Start a new thread so the main thread can display a ProgressDialog while the new thread retrieves, assigns and interrupts the main thread with a new runnable to initiate views. For the ProgressDialog to be shown while all the activity in the new thread is going on, the ProgressDialog must, as mentioned, be started in the main thread and dismissed of course at the end of the new thread. The ProgressDialog must be started as the last thing right before the new thread starts, and everything you wanna wait for must go into the new thread. And remember, if you wanna make UI alterations while waiting and showing ProgressDialog you must interrupt the main thread with a new runnable, which makes the alterations in it's `run()` method, by using `runOnUiThread`.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                ...

                ((ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.contentContainer)).addView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.myCustomContentLayout, null));

                ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.name)).setText(customer.getProperty("name").getValue().toString());

                final ProgressDialog progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Loading", "Please wait...");

                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    protected void run() {
                        ... //get some data, fill some lists and assign some variables...

                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                          public void run() {
                                              initiateActivity();
                                          }
                                      });

                        progressDialog.dismiss();

                        return true;
                    }
                }).start();
}
```

**ORIGINAL POST:**

Hello all and many thanks for reading. :)

Is it really not possible to change your activity layout from a different thread than the main UI-thread?

I'm trying to fill data into a table from another thread while a ProgressDialog is running. Like this.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                ...

                ((ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.contentContainer)).addView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.myCustomContentLayout, null));

                ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.name)).setText(customer.getProperty("name").getValue().toString());

                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                            ... //get some data, fill some lists and assign some variables...

                        initiateActivity();
                    }
                }).start();

                progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Loading", "Please wait...");
}

private void initiateActivity() {
    fillOrderTable();
    initiateGestureview();
    fillCustServiceForCustomer();

    progressDialog.dismiss();
}
```

But as soon as I start altering anything or adding data to tables I get the exception "Activity customerapp.customercentral.Overview has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@46d2fce0 that was originally added here.

And I really don't wanna move the initation methods inside the thread because they are reused from other part of my activity.

Is there a solution to this?

Big thanks! :)

**EDIT:**

Tried this but then the ProgressDialog doesn't show...

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                ...

                ((ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.contentContainer)).addView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.myCustomContentLayout, null));

                ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.name)).setText(customer.getProperty("name").getValue().toString());

                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                ... //get some data, fill some lists and assign some variables...

                                initiateActivity();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }).start();

                progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Loading", "Please wait...");
}
```

The same goes for this...

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                ...

                ((ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.contentContainer)).addView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.myCustomContentLayout, null));

                ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.name)).setText(customer.getProperty("name").getValue().toString());

                new AsyncTask<Boolean, Boolean, Boolean>() {
                    protected void onPreExecute() {
                        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Loading", "Please wait...");
                    }

                    protected Boolean doInBackground(Boolean... unused) {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                ... //get some data, fill some lists and assign some variables...

                                initiateActivity();
                            }
                        });

                        return true;
                    }

                    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean unused) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }).execute(true);
}
```

Comment: If you really want a thread to do something you could use a handler. But in short, only the UI thread can touch the UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**

It might not be the best or the prettiest solution, but it works. Start a new thread so the main thread can display a ProgressDialog while the new thread retrieves, assigns and interrupts the main thread with a new runnable to initiate views. For the ProgressDialog to be shown while all the activity in the new thread is going on, the ProgressDialog must, as mentioned, be started in the main thread and dismissed of course at the end of the new thread. The ProgressDialog must be started as the last thing right before the new thread starts, and everything you wanna wait for must go into the new thread. And remember, if you wanna make UI alterations while waiting and showing ProgressDialog you must interrupt the main thread with a new runnable, which makes the alterations in it's `run()` method, by using `runOnUiThread`.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                ...

                ((ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.contentContainer)).addView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.myCustomContentLayout, null));

                ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.name)).setText(customer.getProperty("name").getValue().toString());

                final ProgressDialog progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Loading", "Please wait...");

                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    protected void run() {
                        ... //get some data, fill some lists and assign some variables...

                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                          public void run() {
                                              initiateActivity();
                                          }
                                      });

                        progressDialog.dismiss();

                        return true;
                    }
                }).start();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No you can't change the UI from another thread. If you have task that do not touch the UI you can use AsynchTask to run them in the background and be notified in the main thread when the task is completed.
But if you need to modify the UI you need to do it in the main thread.
If your code is somewhere else and it is used by other threads you can use runOnUIThread to execute the code that changes the UI

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  ...
progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Loading", "Please wait...");
initiateActivity();
progressDialog.dismiss();

}

private void initiateActivity() {
    fillOrderTable();
    initiateGestureview();
    fillCustServiceForCustomer();
}
```

**EDIT**

Thinking about it: the difference is that you need to exit the onCreate that is what happens if you run a thread that attaches itself to the main thread. So the solution above is not equivalent to your solution for that reason.

Comment: Actually, what i really need is to show a ProgressDialog while `initiateActivity` is running(), which is the method that fills my table with data.

Comment: In that case just use the AsynchTask. You start the progress and then you close it when the task is completed but in the background step do not access the ui

Comment: I checked you code I think it does not make sense to run a thread that the only thing that does is to ask the main thread to do something

Comment: Two things about your implementation with AsyncTask. You are creating a local instance that is going to go out of scope. I think you should store it in a field. You do not need to use Boolean you can use Void

Comment: I don't need it to do anything else, so that's why i don't store it in a field... but somehow i need to make the `ProgressDialog` last the entire time `onCreate()` is running. If I execute an `AsyncTask` it starts a new thread which means i can't alter the layout. If i execute an `AsyncTask` in the previous intent which starts the current intent it'll only show the ProgressDialog while `startActivity` is running, which is way shorter than the `onCreate`.

Comment: `onCreate()` starts `initiateActivity()` which starts `fillOrderTable()`, `fillCustServiceForCustomer()` and  `initiateGestureview()` which create `Views`, retrieve data into those `Views` and fill the UI with those `Views`, and all this takes a while to complete. This is why I want a `ProgressDialog` to be shown when `onCreate()` starts. Because the `ProgressDialog` has to run as long as the initiate methods (inside `onCreate()`) and the initiate methods puts new `Views` in some of the existing `Views` in the UI I can't use `AyncTask`, and I cant use `Threads`.

Comment: And I can't use `runOnUIThread(runnable)` because it just "inserts" itself where the that thread has reached to.

Comment: No you can't show a progress during the onCreate if you still need to change the UI. It looks like you need a kind of double buffering but I have never seen something like that with activities. PS about the variable going out of scope: your AsyncTask would be interrupted I think.

Comment: Even running an "empty" `AsyncTask` that starts the ProgressDialog in `onPreExecute()` ends up not showing the dialog. :-|

Comment: Check my solution in the top of my original post. :)

Comment: isn;t your solution equivalent to what I added in my answer?

Comment: nope... you can't show a progress dialog and continue in the same thread. Whatever you want to do has to happen in another thread. As long as it's not UI alterations. :D If you want to do UI alterations while showing a ProgressDialog you have to start a new thread that interrupts the main ui thread by using runOnUiThread, like my solution. :-) And btw. you dismiss twice... in your example the dialog won't show.

Comment: Ok I forgot the first dismiss. And yes it is not possible. I thought that your code should have not worked either but it is not true. See the change in the answer

Comment: I've tried your suggestion and it dosn't work. The ProgressDialog does not show. My solution works but that's because it only starts a new thread... anything else will make the ProgressDialog not show.

Answer (score 0):

You can not change UI from other threads... TO change UI you have to use "runOnUiThread" or use some handler to make changes..
try this...
make your activity implement Runnable

```
public class myclass extends Activity implements Runnable{
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 ......
progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Loading", "Please wait...");
 Thread thread = new Thread(this);
            thread.start();
}
 public void run() {
            fillOrderTable();
            initiateGestureview();
            fillCustServiceForCustomer();
            handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
    }
 private Handler handler = new Handler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();


            }
    };
}
```

Comment: Understood, but I'm quite new at developing apps for the Android platform. Could you give me an example of how I could do this or point me to good example. Of course I'll be searching for some myself too. Many thanks. :)

Comment: thats all.. put this "runonuithread" inside your "run()" method of thread.. and u can make changes to ui in this part of code

Comment: Thanks. Tried this, but for some reason the ProgressDialog gets dismissed too early. :-|

Comment: can you post your updated code? or tell me if you put initiateActivity()  in runonuithread?

Comment: Sorry what I meant to say was the ProgressDialog doesn't even show. :-| See my original post for the edit. :)

Comment: Didn't make any difference, and as far as I know showing the ProgressDialog must be the last thing to do in a method. :)

Comment: It makes no difference if the part where data is retrieved and assigned is inside or outside the thread, because it's all done on creation of the activity. This means that I'm not really changing the UI but just filling the views. F.ex. I create and fill some TextViews, create some TableRows and add the TextViews to the TableRows and add the TableRows to the TableLayout. But i want a ProgressDialog to be shown while the `onCreate()` method is running. :)

Comment: sorry, doesn't work. First of all the `show(...)` call must be the last or only method call. `fillOrderTable()` and `fillCustServiceForCustomer()` both alter (or add views) to the UI.

Comment: Check my solution in the top of my original post. :)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to *initiate* changing layout from another thread, but all the job has to be done in the UI thread. To do that you can use `Activity.runOnUiThread()`, `View.post()`, `View.postDelayed()` methods, or you can use a `Handler`.

The article [Painless Threading](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html) contains more details regarding this task.

Comment: Check my solution in the top of my original post. :)

Comment: @Hessi-Dude AsyncTask is absolutely redundant since you don't do any work in the AsyncTask thread. You could've put all the code in `onPreExecute` and `onPostExecute` into the Runnable and run it with the `runOnUiThread` with the very same effect. If you intend to do some work in the thread, then you don't do it properly. You should implement `onProgressUpdate` and call `publishProgress()` instead. One other thing: you shouldn't add solutions to the questions. If you come up with a solution yourself, leave it as an answer and mark it as accepted.

Comment: Yes you're right... I was just experimenting with AsyncTask which is why it was done with AsyncTask. couldn't answer my own posts before... didn't have enough reputation points. :)