# Cannot assign value to TextView from parsed Json data in Kotlin Android

Tags: android, kotlin

I have textView in which I want to store data from an API. Following is my code

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.TextView
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder
import okhttp3.*
import java.io.IOException


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val btnFindIp = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnFindIp)
        val txtIP = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txtIP)

        btnFindIp.setOnClickListener {
            fetchJsonData()
        }


    } //onCreate Ends here


    fun fetchJsonData() {
        val url = "https://ipapi.co/json/"
        val request = Request.Builder().url(url).build()
        val httpClient = OkHttpClient()
        val txtIP = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txtIP)



        httpClient.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call?, e: IOException?) {
                println("Failed to execute")
            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call?, response: Response?) {
                val body = response?.body()?.string()
                val gson = GsonBuilder().create()
                val ipData:Ip  = gson.fromJson(body, Ip::class.java)
//                txtIP.text = ipData.ip.toString()
                println(ipData.country_name)

              txtIP.text =  ipData.ip

            }
        })


    }


    data class Ip(
            val ip: String,
            val city: String,
            val region: String,
            val region_code: Any,
            val country: String,
            val country_name: String,
            val continent_code: String,
            val in_eu: Boolean,
            val postal: Any,
            val latitude: Double,
            val longitude: Double,
            val timezone: Any,
            val utc_offset: Any,
            val country_calling_code: String,
            val currency: String,
            val languages: String,
            val asn: String,
            val org: String
    )

}
```

I successfully managed to get data from API and parsed it to the Data class

```
 println(ipData.country_name)
```

this gives the correct output but when I assign data class value to  `txtIP.text =  ipData.ip` nothing is happening, I am sure I missed something since I am really new to Android as well as Kotlin

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Other thread wont let me change Activity layout!? Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9698696/other-thread-wont-let-me-change-activity-layout-android)

Comment: Did you also try logging the value of the `ipData.ip` string that you're setting to your TextView? Perhaps that's empty?

Comment: @Ollaw That is related with Java mine is Kotlin

Comment: @zsmb13 That is not empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't edit UI from another threads. Since the [documentation](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/Callback.html#onResponse-okhttp3.Call-okhttp3.Response-) of OkHTTP says :

> The recipient of the callback may consume the response body on another thread.

you have to set the text in this way :

```
runOnUiThread {txtIP.text = ipData.ip }
```